# Force dropdown to not have the same values

Tags: jquery

I have two dropdowns. A dropdown for Product 1 and a dropdown for Product 2. 
The dropdowns values represents the order of importance.

For example:
[image]

> For Product 1, if I select Order 1, then Product 2’s dropdown should
>   be automatically set to Order 2. (result of Outcome A)
>
> If I was to start with Product 2 and set its dropdown value to Order
>   1, then Product 1’s dropdown should be automatically set to Order 2. (result of Outcome B)

I’ve found some example where the values in the dropdown would becomes disabled once selected. I’m not looking into that kind of behavior since the user may have the liberty to reset his choices therefore, I need all values to be available at all times.

The on `Change` event should simply set the correct values in the appropriate dropdown.

So far(I don't have much), I have the following:

```
<select id="drp1" name="drp1" class="drp">
    <option value="1">Order 1</option>
    <option value="2">Order 2</option>
</select> 

<select id="drp2" name="drp2" class="drp">
    <option value="1">Order 1</option>
    <option value="2">Order 2</option>
</select> 

$("select.drp").on('change', function () {
    var val = $(this).val();
    console.log(val);

    //Figure out which dropdown triggered the change event. 
    //Let its current value selected but now change the dropdown that didn't triggere the change event with another value 
});
```

Comment: You can use $(this).attr("id") to figure out which dropdown triggered the event

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is this what you mean?

```js
$("select.drp").on('change', function () {
  
    var selectedDropDown = $(this).attr("id"); //get the ID of the currently selected drop down
  
    var selectedValue = $(this).val(); //get the value of the currently selected drop down
  
    var otherDropDown = (selectedDropDown == "drp1") ? "drp2" : "drp1"; //get the id of the other drop down
  
    var otherValue = (selectedValue == 1) ? 2 : 1; //get the value that we want the other drop down to be
  
    $("#" + otherDropDown).val(otherValue); //set the other drop down to the opposite of the current drop down.
  
  
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="drp1" name="drp1" class="drp">
    <option value="1">Order 1</option>
    <option value="2">Order 2</option>
</select> 

<select id="drp2" name="drp2" class="drp">
    <option value="1">Order 1</option>
    <option value="2">Order 2</option>
</select>
```

Comment: Yes, this is what I meant. By the way...in the unlikely event that a third dropdown appears, would you happen to know how to make this more generic then only checking for 2 dropdowns ? Thank you by the way

Comment: Need to know what logic it would need to follow - i.e. if I select option 1 in drop-down 1 then should drop-down 2 be option 2 or 3 or 4 and should drop-down 3 be 2 or 3 or 4? If you want to post a scenario I can offer some guidance.

Comment: I see what you mean...once the user selects a value in dropdown1, it's impossible to decide for him what will be the selected value in dropdown2 or dropdown3...which makes perfect sense. But...once he selects an item in dropdown 2, only then will it be possible to pre-select dropdown3 since it's the last dropdown. Do you know where I could find such an example?

Comment: It is actually impossible with more than 2 drop-downs - but the following fiddle should give you an idea of how you might address the problem - you would then have to validate by checking all options are selected before submitting http://jsfiddle.net/x4E5Q/371/

Comment: Yes, I see what you mean and I agree. The only issue I have with the example is that the values become disabled as I make selections. If I change my mind, I need to go back to the first dropdown and change my selection. I'd rather have the ability to select anything in any point in any dropdown, re-calculating the possibilities and re-selected them. Thanks for the example, I'll see if I can try something.

Answer (score 1):

So, the logic is.

on document ready, you make second select box to **order 2**. As soon as user click, it will detect which dropdown has selected and apply a other value to dropdown which is not selected.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('#drp2').val(2)
$("select.drp").on('click', function () {
    var val = $(this).val();
  console.log(val);
    if(val == "1") {
      $(".drp").not(this).val(2);
    }
    else {
       $(".drp").not(this).val(1);
    }
});
  });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="drp1" name="drp1" class="drp">
    <option value="1">Order 1</option>
    <option value="2">Order 2</option>
</select> 

<select id="drp2" name="drp2" class="drp">
    <option value="1">Order 1</option>
    <option value="2">Order 2</option>
</select>
```

Comment: Yes, I like this solution as well with the .not(). Btw, I didn't mark your answer as the correct one not because its wrong, on the contrary, but because Graham Ritchie answered first. That's why. But thanks for showing me this, I like it.

Comment: haha nvm. This is reason why I love jQuery and coding. Many methods many solution to one problem. :)

Answer (score 0):

I just prepare example for you please check out below fiddle.

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/pn843jgt/)

Here is Code:

```
$("select.drp").on('change', function () {
    var val = $(this).val();
    console.log(val);
   var selectedid=$(this).attr("id");

   var selectedIndex = $("select#"+selectedid).prop('selectedIndex');
 //  alert(selectedIndex);
   if(selectedid=="drp1")
   {
      if(selectedIndex==0)
      {
        $("select#drp2").prop('selectedIndex',1);
      }
      else
      {
         $("select#drp2").prop('selectedIndex',0);
      }

   }
   else
   {
    if(selectedIndex==0)
      {
        $("select#drp1").prop('selectedIndex',1);
      }
      else
      {
         $("select#drp1").prop('selectedIndex',0);
      }

   }

    //Figure out which dropdown triggered the change event. 
    //Let its current value selected but now change the dropdown that didn't triggere the change event with another value 
});
```